# SQL SERVER 2008 Date difference

Tags: sql-server-2008

**I have a column name logdate which has dates in following format**

2011-01-04 23:35:44.000

I want to select other columns in between 1st June 2011 till 30th June 2011 so the query should be

```
select * from abc where logdate = ?
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `>=` and `<`:

```
SELECT *
FROM abc
WHERE logdate >= '20110601' AND logdate < '20110701'
```

Comment: thanks that worked how do i export these records to CSV, can it be done automatically ?

Comment: @user580950,  to export to CSV, in management studio right-click the results pane > Save Results As...

Comment: Just be careful about YYYY-MM-DD format - this can break depending on settings (e.g. try `SET LANGUAGE FRENCH`). Much safer to use YYYYMMDD.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to manipulate SQL datetimes and strings that represent SQL datetimes:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724(v=sql.105).aspx

A very straightforward way to do this would be to use >= < operators.

```
SELECT *
FROM abc
WHERE logdate >= '20110601'
    AND logdate < '20110701'
```

The reason you want to use < July 1 as opposed to <= June 30 is that the string parsing on a date assumes it is midnight on that date, and it will exclude any values later than June 30 at 12 AM.

Comment: Just be careful about YYYY-MM-DD format - this can break depending on settings (e.g. try `SET LANGUAGE FRENCH`). Much safer to use YYYYMMDD.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `LogDate` is a `DateTime` column, you can use the following query to get the full range of the month:

```
WHERE logdate >= '2011-06-01' AND logdate < '2011-07-01'
```